# Accessing Subversion VisualSVN Server repository over internet

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I'm new to Apache Subversion. We are a group of people thinking to work on a project in java. Some of us are based in different locations. I've been surfing the web for some common repository to share code across all the team members and I came across VisualSVN server.

I was able to setup a repository and my friend, we live together, share the same Wi-Fi router can access the repository using TortoiseSVN client because we are on same network, but a friend who lives far away can't use this repository of mine.

This repository is not accessible by him for I dont know what all reasons, may be my IP is not static or some other reasons which I dont know about.

Please let me know how to make that repo available for him using SVN client only, if possible.

Comment: Have you considered to setup port-forwarding on your router or using dynamic DNS service (if you don't have static IP)?

Comment: I've setup a svn server and used it remotely a couple years ago, so i don't remember all the details.  I do think bahrep is correct.  you don't need a static ip address, but remember that a dynamic IP will change every now and then.  It's not very often.

Comment: @bahrep - how to do that...i dont have any idea abt it...can u give me any reference material it will be great :)

Comment: Just Google it, it's pretty common issue. The same as setting up any web server to be avaliable from the Internet. As well, consider @Henrik's answer about using cloud service such as Windows Azure or Amazon EC2.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend far away can't use the repository because it's internal to your network. You need to configure the firewall/router on your network for port forwarding to send requests through to your internal server.

Anytime your public IP changes, your friend will have to `relocate` his working copies. Or you can avail yourself of one of the many dynamic DNS services so that he doesn't have to do this.

Bear in mind that exposing a server to the internet can expose you to security issues. If you aren't familiar with managing a more or less public server on the internet, you could find yourself in a heap of trouble.

I would suggest that you look at a repository hosting service to handle this repository for you, instead of trying to do it yourself with an old PC in your basement. Recommending such a service is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Repository hosting service? I'd better consider using Windows Azure or setting up dynamic DNS service. SVN hosters are not flexible and usually run outdated version of SVN.

Comment: Why spend money on those at all when Bitbucket is free for up to 5 users? Then you don't have to worry about *any* of the administrative overhead (set CVCS vs DVCS religious wars aside for a moment)

Answer (score 1):

You should seriously consider setting up a central SVN repository, use a VDS,
I use AWS for my SVN server, never encountered any connectivity issues and it's backed up and I don't have to worry about power failures.

Comment: can u throw some more light...how to do so ?

Comment: @jasmeet24 it's pretty easy to install VisualSVN Server on cloud service, such as Amazon EC2, Windows Azure etc. It's very cheap if you are only 2-10 developers acessing the VisualSVN Server instance.

Comment: @jasmeet24 Marco Pasin did a great job on describing the solution: http://mictorino.wordpress.com/2013/01/16/visualsvn-on-azure-vm/

IT'S VERY EASY TO INTSTALL VisualSVN Server on Windows Azure!